# Difficults deploying circleci v.2 to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3, circleci, circleci-2.0

I'm a newbie to to CI/CD stuff and I've been trying for a couple of days to deploy an application to our bucket at AWS S3.

I tried this:
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-set-up-continuous-deployment-to-aws-s3-using-circleci-in-under-30-minutes-a8e268284098

this:
https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/continuous-deployment-with-amazon-s3/

And this:
https://medium.com/@zlwaterfield/circleci-s3-upload-dbffa0956b6f

But somehow I wasn't able to succeed with my attempt to do so. Circleci says my file successful was build, but somehow no deploy was made and no error msg was received. My AWS permissions are set, so it's being really frustrating this task.

Here's my final file:

```
jobs: 
  build: 
    docker: 
      - 
        image: "circleci/openjdk:8-jdk"
    environment: 
      JVM_OPTS: "-Xmx3200m"
      TERM: dumb
    steps: 
      - checkout
      - 
        restore_cache: 
          keys: 
            - "v1-dependencies-{{ checksum \"build.gradle\" }}"
            - v1-dependencies-
      - 
        run: "gradle dependencies"
      - 
        save_cache: 
          key: "v1-dependencies-{{ checksum \"build.gradle\" }}"
          paths: 
            - ~/.gradle
      - 
        run: "gradle test"
    working_directory: ~/repo
  deploy: 
    machine: 
      enabled: true
    steps: 
      - 
        run: 
          command: 'aws s3 sync ${myAppName}/ s3://${myBucketName} --region us-west-2'
          name: Deploy
    working_directory: ~/repo
version: 2
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Updated: I was able to find a way. Here's my solution in case anyone needs it:

```
 jobs: 
  build: 
    docker: 
      - 
        image: "circleci/openjdk:8-jdk"
    environment: 
      JVM_OPTS: "-Xmx3200m"
      TERM: dumb
    steps: 
      - checkout
      - 
        restore_cache: 
          keys: 
            - "v1-dependencies-{{ checksum \"build.gradle\" }}"
            - v1-dependencies-
      - 
        run: "gradle dependencies"
      - 
        save_cache: 
          key: "v1-dependencies-{{ checksum \"build.gradle\" }}"
          paths: 
            - ~/.gradle
      - 
        run: "gradle build"
      - 
        run: "gradle test"
      - run: 
          command: "sudo apt-get -y -qq install awscli"
          name: "Install awscli"
      - 
        run: 
          command: "aws configure list"
          name: "show credentials"
      - 
        run: 
          command: "aws s3 ls"
          name: "List all buckets"
      - 
        run: 
          command: "aws s3 sync /tmp/app/myProject/build/libs s3://my-aws-bucket"
          name: "Deploy to my AWS bucket"
        working_directory: /tmp/app
    version: 2
    workflows: 
      build-deploy: 
        jobs: 
          - 
            build-job: 
              filters: 
                branches: 
                  only: 
                    - /development.*/
                    - /staging.*/
      version: 2
```

Comment: You might want to update your answer with your solution.

Comment: For quick debugging and testing you could run your build locally using circleci CLI: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/local-cli/

Comment: @stmllr tried using it, but didn't like it as this circleci cli doesn't work well. The same file was running perfectly on circleci website doesn't work on the local client.

Comment: @RafaelPaz cli client has limitations: caching does not work as well as ENV variables from settings are not available

Comment: @rafaelpaz how did you fix it? Please update you answer with the solution.